# excel macro save sheets as csv with specific delimiter and enclosure

Tags: vba, excel

I am a total dummy as for vb and excel, have tried to combine 2 macros that I have found around here, into 1, but obviously did something terribly wrong and now i'm stuck.. First I just used this macro (saved it in as personal.xlsb so as to be able to use it in any workbook)

```
    Sub CSVFile()

    Dim SrcRg As Range
    Dim CurrRow As Range
    Dim CurrCell As Range
    Dim CurrTextStr As String
    Dim ListSep As String
    Dim FName As Variant
    FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")

    ListSep = ";"
      If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Set SrcRg = Selection
      Else
        Set SrcRg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      End If
    Open FName For Output As #1
    For Each CurrRow In SrcRg.Rows
      CurrTextStr = ìî
    For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
      CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & """" & GetUTF8String(CurrCell.Value) & """" & ListSep
    Next
    While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
      CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
    Wend
    Print #1, CurrTextStr
    Next
    Close #1
    End Sub
```

That plus the GetUTF8String function code. Now that was working fine. Then I have thought well why not just experiment with my limited (that is a serious understatement) vb understanding, added the following code and changed the CSVFile sub into a function, which I then called from the sub below, with the output file name as a parameter (to be used instead FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename). I thought yeah, this code saves all sheets automatically, now let's just make sure that the encoding and delimiter/enclosure setting function runs before each sheet is saved. It doesn't seem right but I thought hey why not try..

```
Public Sub SaveAllSheetsAsCSV()
On Error GoTo Heaven

' each sheet reference
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
' path to output to
Dim OutputPath As String
' name of each csv
Dim OutputFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Save the file in current director
OutputPath = ThisWorkbook.Path


If OutputPath <> "" Then
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' save for each sheet
For Each Sheet In Sheets

    OutputFile = OutputPath & Application.PathSeparator & Sheet.Name & ".csv"

    ' make a copy to create a new book with this sheet
    ' otherwise you will always only get the first sheet

    Sheet.Copy
    ' this copy will now become active
     CSVFile(OutputFile)
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=OutputFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV,     CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End If

Finally:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exit Sub

Heaven:
MsgBox "Couldn't save all sheets to CSV." & vbCrLf & _
        "Source: " & Err.Source & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Number: " & Err.Number & " " & vbCrLf & _
        "Description: " & Err.Description & " " & vbCrLf

GoTo Finally
End Sub
```

Saved that and with that I have managed to achieve something very different. On opening any workbooks, that macro runs and opens up my sheets from that particular workbook as csv files (without saving them). Now I am like Alice in Wonderland. How come it is running on file open? That is not desirable, so I went back to the macro code and changed it back to just the csvfile sub. Well that didn't help, no idea what I did there, was definitely editing the same macro... So I deleted the macro, the modul, I cannot imagine where the thing now is but it's still running + I get this warning that macros were deactivated. Can't get rid of it! Now lads, I'm sorry for the total lack of professionality from my side, this was just supposed to be a small favor for a client, without wasting loads of time learning vb, coz my boss doesn't like that... I am of course interested in how to achieve the goal of saving the sheets automatically after setting the deimiter and enclosure in them. And at this moment I am very interested in how to get rid of that macro and where it is hiding.. What have I done?! Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with the line

```
OutputPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Because you are running this from your personal.xlsb which is stored in your XLSTART folder it has created the CSV files in the same location. When Excel starts it will try and load any files that it finds in that location.

Just locate your XLSTART folder and delete any CSV files you find there.

Try using

```
OutputPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

XLSTART folder location, dependent on your system, is probably something like:

```
C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
```